# Get environment variable from kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes

What's the best way to list out the environment variables in a kubernetes pod?

(Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051747/get-environment-variable-from-docker-container/34052766), but for Kube, not Docker.)

Comment: `kubectl -n <namespace> exec <pod_name> -- env` ?

Comment: I suggest only by parsing of `kubectl describe pod <podname>`.

Comment: @EgorStambakio yeah also just found this. thanks!

Comment: Trying to tag @AlexeyUsharovski : thank you! If you would like to post it as an answer yourself, please let me know and I will delete mine.

Comment: Other ways see:
[This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121439/how-to-parse-json-format-output-of-kubectl-get-pods-using-jq-and-create-an-arr)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`kubectl exec -it <pod_name> -- env`

Comment: Note: No need for the `-it` flags. The best answer is actually Egor Stambakio's in the OP comments (it also covers when in a namespace).

Comment: This only works if env is installed in the container.

Answer (score 14):

Both answers have the following issues:

1. They assume you have the permissions to start pod, which is not the case in a locked-down environment
2. They start a new pod, which is invasive and may give different environment variables than "a[n already running] kubernetes pod"

To inspect a running pod and get its environment variables, one can run:

```sh
kubectl describe pod <podname>
```

This is from [Alexey Usharovski's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198188/get-environment-variable-from-kubernetes-pod#comment104614421_59198188).

I am hoping this gives more visibility to your great answer. If you would like to post it as an answer yourself, please let me know and I will delete mine.

Comment: This doesn't work for environment variables sourced from a ConfigMap or Secret via `envFrom`.

Answer (score 8):

**kubectl set env** can be used for both setting environment variables and reading them .

You can use **kubectl set env [resource] --list** option to get them.

For example to list all environment variables for all PODs in the DEFAULT namespace:

```
kubectl set env pods --all --list
```

or for an specific POD in a given namespace

```
kubectl set env pod/<pod-NAME> --list -n <NAMESPACE-NAME>
```

or for a deployment in DEFAULT namespace

```
kubectl set env deployment/<deployment-NAME> --list
```

this is better than running command inside the POD as in some cases the OS command may not exist in very slim containers

For more see : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#set

Comment: if the env pass from configmap you won't see the env value. But then you have to check the configmap.

Answer (score 7):

Execute in bash:

`kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- printenv | grep -i env`

You will get all environment variables that consists `env` keyword.

Comment: Do you know why this command only returns the firs occurrence but not all the matched strings?

Comment: This only works if `printenv` is installed in the container.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
kubectl exec <POD_NAME> -- sh -c 'echo $VAR_NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally use:

```
kubectl exec -it <POD_NAME> -- env | grep "<VARIABLE_NAME>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Kubernetes deployments or statefulsets usually manage pods, and pods inherit the variables from their manifests, I would use the `kubectl describe ...` instead of `kubectl exec -it ...` approach since finding the correct dynamic pod name is not always easy or fast.

For example:

```javascript
kubectl describe deployment/my-app -n my_namespace | grep MY_VAR_NAME
```

is more robust and works better for me.